# Issue with inspecting QJsonObject in QtCreator with CDB

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, cdb, qjsonobject

Recently updated to Qt 5.15.0.
But now, I see some problems displaying JSON objects in the watchlist. Found nothing while digging google last few hours.

See the screenshots:

[image: Code]

[image: The application output]

[image: And the watchlist]

**Any ideas what is  wrong with the settings ? Or debug helpers ? Or it is QT bug ?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the issue. I had to upgrade the QT Creator. Did not notice that Maintenance tool did not update the Creator too.